# Kafka Consumer polls fewer messages when the messages are larger (MapR Streams)

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, mapr, mapr-streams

We are facing an issue while running a Kafka consumer (Java). The poll returns fewer messages when the messages are larger. We have tried increasing different config parameters while constructing the consumer such as `fetch.min.bytes`, `fetch.max.bytes`, `max.partition.fetch.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` but the output is the same. (5-8 messages)

We found that the messages in a single poll amount to roughly 10KB in size. This was found when we tried to get the sum of byte length (`message.value().getBytes().length`) of the ConsumerRecords returned on a poll.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem.

To me, it sounds like all the messages eventually arrive, but they don't necessarily arrive batched together in as large a batch when messages are bigger.

Is that correct?

Comment: yes @TedDunning For eg, there are 10,000 records in the topic, the poll fetches only 5-6 messages at a time. I want to increase this batch.

Comment: @TedDunning any solutions?

Comment: Feedback from others is that changing these parameters has a substantial effect. What I am hearing from you is that there is no effect. In my own experience, that often means that I am not actually changing the parameters I think I am changing either due to changing the wrong config file or because another config is over-riding my changes. Is that possible in your case?

Comment: I have changed these parameters in my code and I see these changed values in the log as well which kafka generates (producer and consumer config).

Comment: I see that some parameters in MapR are ignored. such as receive buffer bytes and send buffer bytes, can these parameters have some impact on what i want to achieve?